# Conflict while using svn in subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, conflict, subclipse

we are using subclipse with to save our project in svn directory. But facing conflicts during the following scenario:

I modify a file say "file1.java" in the directory, update and commit it. Then, my colleague also has modifications to be save on the same file. So he updates and tries to commit his changes. But it doesn't allow him to commit as there is conflict and it shows the conflict on the same line!!
Any one has the idea of how to resolve this??

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague has to solve the conflict in the file by editing the correspondent parts. Usually they are visible by section markers like `<<<<<<< .mine`.

After the code has been cleaned, mark the file as "Resolved". Afterwards the file can be commited back into the repository.

Comment: so everything has to be manual here.. svn can't handle this conflict is the end tag line now!?

Comment: How should SVN know what can be discarded and what have to be kept? SVN does not know anything about programming languages - conflict resolving is always a manual job to be performed by humans.

Answer (score 0):

There's an existing question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537980/subclipse-conflict-resolution).

Generally the idea is that Subversion does not try to work out how your change will be integrated with the change already committed to the repository. So, it wants you to manually check and resolve the conflict.

oops missed the bus.

Congrats.

In case you have problems with changed package names [(tree conflicts)](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2010/11/resolving-tree-conflicts/)