# How to Resolve Conflict in Eclipse SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

While using Eclipse in coding and SVN for the team repository, I am having trouble in having conflicts in Eclipse.

Supposing I have a conflict and there 3 automatically generated files. Once I have resolved the conflict, I can't find the command how to commit the solution of the conflict and automatically deleting the generated files.

In SVN outside Eclipse, there is a Resolve Conflict function and the codes will be updated. Also, the generated files for the conflict will be deleted. Is there a similar method in Eclipse or I have to manually delete the generated files and commit the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subclipse conflict resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537980/subclipse-conflict-resolution)

Comment: I've found a similar question, you can find the answer here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537980/subclipse-conflict-resolution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537980/subclipse-conflict-resolution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aside from the answers shown in the related question, it is also possible to solve the conflict, delete the automatically generated files and **Mark as Merged**.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions mentioned resolved my issue.
When I would right-click on the folder, there was no option to resolve the conflict or mark as resolved or anything.

The way I resolved it in Eclipse (with Subclipse plugin), was right-clicking on the folder and selecting "Show Tree Conflicts".  This opened up a view pane in Eclipse called "SVN Tree Conflicts" which showed the folder in question.

I right-clicked that message and selected "Resolve".  Then a window popped up, asking what I wanted to do.  I basically unchecked all the boxes, that had to do with accepting left file or right file or merging.  Because basically, I just wanted to mark the conflict as resolved, and accept the folder as it was, from the repository.

Then I was able to continue updating my project without issues.

Answer (score 3):

The way I do it is change perspective to '**Team Synchronising**' and in the synchronise tab you right click the file and select '**Mark as merged**'

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse on the Team menu you can choose either `edit conflicts` or `mark resolved`

see [Subclipse conflict resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537980/subclipse-conflict-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (similar to princepieros) is to Right-Click your project -> Execute an entire commit -> It will show "Conflict" items -> Right-Click these items and hit "Mark as Merged" or "Edit Conflict". This did the trick for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following steps:

1. Go to the Package Explorer View. Mark the folders that you want to be checked for the conflicts (I selected all).
2. Right click and go to "Team" -> "Synchronize with Repository". Wait a moment.
3. In the "Team Synchronizing"-Perspective, you should see all changes files (incoming, outgoing, conflicted files etc.)

- the conflicted files should be extended by the prefix, and have this structure:

**filename.java**                      <-- Original file

**filenam.java.mine**                 <-- My file

**filename.java.revisionNumber**    <-- Their file (incoming file that caused conflict)

4. Right click of the original file and choose "Edit conflict"
5. Right click and .mark as resolved