# Subversive Eclipse SVN folder remains in conflict

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm trying to commit using subversive svn in eclipse. But, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: 'C:\Users\_\Documents\Project\src\rule' remains in conflict
```

When I look into the files under "rule folder" (using package explorer), there is nothing in conflict..

Screenshot of the package explorer:
http://sdrv.ms/GGti1s

From other people's posts, I tried "update" and "synchronize with repository". No success though. It just doesn't let me commit!! I'm guessing it's because I need a way to tell that the conflict is solved, but I have no idea how. Any help??

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions mentioned resolved my issue. When I would right-click on the folder, there was no option to resolve the conflict or mark as resolved or anything.

The way I resolved it in Eclipse (with Subclipse plugin), was right-clicking on the folder and selecting "Show Tree Conflicts". This opened up a view pane in Eclipse called "SVN Tree Conflicts" which showed the folder in question.

I right-clicked that message and selected "Resolve". Then a window popped up, asking what I wanted to do. I basically unchecked all the boxes, that had to do with accepting left file or right file or merging. Because basically, I just wanted to mark the conflict as resolved, and accept the folder as it was, from the repository.

Then I was able to continue updating my project without issues

Comment: Why do you paste the same answer to multiple questions? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24450059/761095

Comment: the OP is using subversive, not subclipse

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with SVN in eclipse.
It help me following:

1. Right click on conflicting folder -> **Team** -> **Synchronize with Repository**;
2. Then go to -> **Team Synchronizing** perspective
3. In **Synchronize** tab right click on conflicting folder - **Commit** or **Override and Commit**